# Linker settings are missing in Project Property Pages

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2019

I've opened one of my old projects (developed some 5 years ago with VS2015) and, while trying to solve linking issues, discovered that there is no Linker settings in the project properties:
[image: VS2019 Project Property Pages without Linker]

Has anyone encountered such problem before?
I wonder how this can be resolved.
Is there some specific option in vcxproj which can disable linker settings completely?
I have no problems with other projects (even old ones) - the Linker settings are shown, so it's not an issue with the installation, but rather a problem with this specific project or rather projects in this solution, since the static library project doesn't have Librarian settings either.
Deleting `.vs` folder has no effect.
Changing properties (like choosing another platform toolset or Windows SDK version + deleting `.vs` folder) doesn't bring the linker settings back.
Apparently this solution drives VS2019 crazy.

Version: VS2019 16.11.16 (so it's quite fresh)

Comment: Maybe you want to compare the `vcxproj` files in your version control?

Comment: @drescherjm , thanks for the hint. VCS history doesn't reveal the problem. Comparing the "bad" project with another good one doesn't show the cause tiehre. I tried to open one of the projects from another folder after copying its `vcxproj` there , and the issue doesn't happen then. So it is probably caused by another files.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that one of the referenced NuGet packages (specifically [OpenCV-Native.4.5.2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV-Native/4.5.2.2)) could somehow remove Linker/Librarian settings from Project Properties Pages (probably some conflict with VS2019).
Removing `...\packages\OpenCV-Native.4.5.2.2` and reloading solution immediately solves the problem.
Building step automagically recreates the folder, so after reloading the solution the issue is back.
I will contact the maintainer to let him know about the issue.